# Last echo'd HTML source not shown (shown completely red in 'view source')

Tags: php, html

I was actually working on an answer for someone elses question untill I run into something odd. The question was about writing a pagination system. The user wanted something extra added to his current system. So I've written the following code:

```
<?php

// Database Settings
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = '';

// Establish Connection to the Database
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. $dbhost .';dbname='. $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));

// Selecting the data from table but with limit
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name ASC LIMIT :start, :page';

// Prepare query
$pre = $dbh->prepare($query);

// Binding values
$pre->bindParam(':start', $start_from);
$pre->bindParam(':page', $per_page);

// Results per page
$per_page=2;

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page=1;
}

// Page will start from 0 and Multiple by Per Page
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

?>

<!-- Start building HTML table -->
<table>

<?php

// Execute query
try {
    $pre->execute();

    // Fetch all results
    $results = $pre->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Loop through results
    foreach($results as $data){

        // Display results in HTML table
        echo "<tr>";

        // Add/Remove your column names here
        echo "<td>". $data['column_name'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $data['column_name'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $data['column_name'] ."</td>";

        // Close HTML table row
        echo "</tr>";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'MySQL query error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>

<!-- End building HTML table -->
</table>

<div>
    <?php

    // Now select all data from table
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM users';

    // Prepare the query
    $pre = $dbh->prepare($query);

    // Execute the query
    try {
        $pre->execute();

        // Count the results
        $total_records = $pre->rowCount();

        // Keep a record of total number of rows
        $total_rows = $total_records;

        // Using ceil function to divide the total records on per page
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

        // Going to first page
        echo "<center><a href='pagination.php?page=1'>First Page</a> ";

        // Showing number of pages in between last page
        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){
            echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=". $i ."'>". $i ."</a> ";
        }

        // Going to last page
        echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=". $total_pages .">Last Page</a></center> ";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'MySQL query error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    // Calculate first and last item on current page
    $first = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
    $last = $page * $per_page;

    // Showing the results
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Showing ". $first ." to ". $last ." in total record of ". $total_rows;

    ?>
</div>
```

The code returns no errors and seems to display the data just fine. However, everything echo'd from line 112 (underneath `// Going to last page`) won't display on the page. It does display in the HTML source code with the correct values. But it's completely marked red in both Firefox and Chrome.

I've never encountered this before and I'm wandering what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem generally means that your HTML is not well formed.

Look at that line :

```
echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=". $total_pages .">Last Page</a></center> ";
```

A simple quote is missing before `>Last Page` ;)

it should be

```
echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=". $total_pages ."'>Last Page</a></center> ";
```

Comment: Ah you are absolutely correct. Thanks a lot! This is actually quite a usefull feature. I will accept your answer once it's possible.